# How to copy Input Stream to folder in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to copy a copy InputStream to file using this :

```
InputStream inputStrJw1 = null; 
inputStrJw1 = this.uploadedArb.getInputstream();
                        
File destFileJw = new File("D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 9.0\\webapps\\portal\\Islamic\\Ad3ya\\ARB\\");

FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStrJw1, destFileJw);
                       
inputStrJw1.close();
this.uploadedArb.getInputstream().close();
```

However, I'm receiving this error :

> java.io.IOException: File 'D:\Program Files\Apache Software
> Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\portal\Islamic\Ad3ya\ARB' exists but is
> a directory

Comment: You can't, a folder contains files that contain data, a folder cannot contain raw data in itself. You need to write to a file instead of a directory.

Comment: you cannot write a data on the directory, you can do it only on file

Comment: am writing it on a file as you can see am creating a file 
File destFileJw = new File("D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 9.0\\webapps\\portal\\Islamic\\Ad3ya\\ARB\\");

, but I don't know why it been considered a directory !!

Comment: Because you have trailing slashes (or back slashes) in the path. If something ends in a slash (or back slash) then it is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Exception message and the documentation is clear. Destination should be a file, not just the directory. You have given the directory as the destination.

> Copies bytes from an InputStream source to a file destination. The directories up to destination will be created if they don't already exist. destinationwill be overwritten if it already exists.

Comment: why it been considered directory not a folder the (ARB) in the path is a folder !!

Comment: To make it simple, folder or directory stores a collection of files. In Java, File class can represent both directory and a end file. In your code, you are still using a directory to dump the content, which the library can't. So, we need to specify a end file( such as .txt, .mp3 etc). Some thing like this,

File destFileJw = new File("D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 9.0\\webapps\\portal\\Islamic\\Ad3ya\\ARB\\userFile.arb");

Comment: @Niyas ,, you know what !! thankkkkk youuuu it works

Comment: @GoviS: The difference between this answer and the comments is that this answer is an answer and the comments are comments, and answers belong in answers, not in comments. You cannot vote on comments, you cannot accept comments, and comments are ephemeral, they can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change There in your line.

```
File destFolder = new File("storage/emulated/0/folder/");
if(!file.exists())
destFolder.mkDirs();

File destFileJw = new File(destFolder.getAbsolutePath()+"/file.txt");
```

I hope this may help you.